# Pasar variables php recibidas en post a Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Hola les cuento que aun estoy dando mis primeros pasos en esto.. por tal razon acudo a ustedes.. pues un colaborador me ayudó a terminar y que funcionara un código el cuaL pongo a continuación: (he creado un nuevo hilo de conversación por que aquella consulta fue respondida me perdonan si es asi)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
 var tipow = "contenido de tu variable $tipow2";
var anow = "contenido de tu variable $anow2";
        var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
          "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
           "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                url :"normat.php", // json datasource
                 data: {'tipow' : tipow, 'anow' : anow},
                type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                error: function(){  // error handling
                    $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                    $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3"> No hay Información </th></tr></tbody>');
                    $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                }
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Como haria para pasarle a las variables var unas variables php recibidas mediante post y ponerlas aca...

```
$tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
$anow2=$_POST['anow'];

var tipow = "contenido de tu variable $tipow2";
var anow = "contenido de tu variable $anow2";
```

he intentado asi y no me resulta

```
var tipow = '<?php echo $tipow2; ?>';
 var anow = '<?php echo $anow2; ?>';
```

pero si le escribo manualmente si funciona.. pero deseo que allí se pongan las variables traídas en post

```
var tipow = "DECRETOS";
var anow = "2017";
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes enviar tus variables php a javascript de la siguiente manera :

```
    <?php
    $tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
    $anow2=$_POST['anow'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tipow = "<?php echo $tipow2 ?>";
        var anow = "<?php echo $anow2 ?>";
    } );
</script>
```

verifica que se esten enviando `tipow` y `anow` por POST, el funcionamiento deberia ser el siguiente archivo1.php envia por `tipow` y `anow` al archivo2.php donde deberia estar el codigo que pongo arriba.

Segun la documentación la forma de pasar los valores a JavaScript según los tipos de datos seria de la siguiente forma:

```
 <?php
$bool = true;
$num = 10;
$str = "cadena";
?>
```

se enviarian a JavaScript de la siguiente forma :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// el valor de bool seria "" si $bool es false, "1" si es true
var bool = "<?php echo $bool ?>"; 

// resultado de para valores numericos con y sin comillas
var num = <?php echo $num ?>; // 10
var str_num = "<?php echo $num ?>"; // "10" (como cadena)

var str = "<?php echo $str ?>"; // 'resultado seria "cadena"'
</script>
```

Espero sea lo que estas buscando, si continuas con el error puedes compartir mas detalle para poder ayudar.

, saludos.

Comment: Hola no entiendo por que la variable la muestra en un echo que hago pero no la pasa a la variable JS.. pues quiere decir que si esta pasando la informacion de la smismas pero no se por que no es capturada por los:

var tipow = "<?php echo $tipow2 ?>";
var anow = "<?php echo $anow2 ?>";

Comment: Hola, puede que derrepente sea el orden, quiza al momento de que le pasas la variables a javascript las de php aún no estan disponibles, pero solo es una suposición ya que no he visto tu codigo, si puedes compartir más detalles sobre eso te podria ayudar de mejor manera.

Comment: Angeldev te envió en la Respuesta siguiente los codigos que uso...

Comment: Revisa la ultima respuesta al parecer es un problema con los espacios de tu <option value=" <?php echo $row['ano'] ?> " >,

Comment: @Eduardo probaste asignándolo así?:

var tipow = <?php echo json_encode($tipow2) ?>;
var anow = <?php echo json_encode($anow2 ) ?>;

Answer (score 0):

[image: PANTALLAZO]

Hola Gracia spor responder, efectivamente hize este cambio de recoger las variables asi...

```
    var tipow = "<?php echo $tipow2 ?>";
    var anow = "<?php echo $anow2 ?>";
```

pero no me muestra nada, verifico si las variables tineen algo y si tienen pues pasan el titulo de lo seleccionado y lo muestran en la cabecera del datatable..

```
<th colspan="5"><?php echo $tipow2  ?>  <?php echo $anow2  ?></th>
```

Pero no entiendo por que no pasan a las variables Js usando esto

```
    var tipow = "<?php echo $tipow2 ?>";
    var anow = "<?php echo $anow2 ?>";
```

en el archivo que las recibe uso

```
$tipoow = $_POST["tipow"]; 
$anoow = $_POST["anow"];
```

Answer (score 0):

El Formulario que envió la consulta son dos select que toman los años y los tipos de documentos agregados de una Base de datos los campos se llaman anow y tipow respectivamente...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <?php
    $serveru = 'localhost';
    $usernameu = 'usuario';
    $passwordu = 'contrasena';
    $database_nameu = 'normatividad';
    $conexionu = new mysqli($serveru,$usernameu,$passwordu,$database_nameu);

    if ( $conexionu->connect_error ) {  die('Error de Conexión'. $conexionu->connect_error);
    }else{
        //echo 'Conexion OK';
    }

    $query = 'SELECT ano FROM normativa GROUP BY ano ORDER BY ano DESC';
    $query2 = 'SELECT tipo FROM normativa GROUP BY tipo ORDER BY tipo ASC';

    $result = $conexionu->query($query);
    $result2 = $conexionu->query($query2);

    ?>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Normatividad</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .container #employee-grid thead tr th form table tr td {
        text-align: left;
    }
    </style>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        ul.sf-menu ul li a, ul.sf-menu ul li span.separator {
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }
    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
                    <style>
                div.container {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    max-width:760px;
                }
                div.header {
                    margin: 100px auto;
                    line-height:30px;
                    max-width:760px;
                }
                body {
                    background: #f7f7f7;
                    color: #333;
                    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
          <p><a href="index_administracion.php"><img src="arribanormatividad.png" width="629" height="133"></a></p>
          <table id="employee-grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th width="100%">&nbsp;</th>
                          </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th><p>Seleciona el Tipo de Documento a visualizar:</p>
                                <form name="form1" method="post" action="buscarnorma.php" >
                                  <table width="467" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2">
                                    <tr>
                                      <td width="181" height="44">Vigencia:</td>
                                      <td width="276"><select style="font-size:15pt" name="anow" id="anow" required>
                                        <option value="" >Seleccione</option>
                                        <?php    
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )    
        {
            ?>
                                        <option value=" <?php echo $row['ano'] ?> " ><?php echo $row['ano']; ?></option>
                                        <?php
        }    
        ?>
                                      </select></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="34">Tipo Normatividad:</td>
                                      <td><select style="font-size:15pt" name="tipow" id="tipow" required>
                                        <option value="" >Seleccione</option>
                                        <?php    
        while ( $row = $result2->fetch_array() )    
        {
            ?>
                                        <option value=" <?php echo $row['tipo'] ?> " ><?php echo $row['tipo']; ?></option>
                                        <?php
        }    
        ?>
                                      </select></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td height="48">&nbsp;</td>
                                      <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Consultar"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </form>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p>
                              <p>&nbsp;</p></th>
                          </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th>          
          Realizado por: Eduardo Arroyo Teher&aacute;n</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

Ahora este script recoge las variables post que envia el formulario 

    $tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
    $anow2=$_POST['anow'];

y hace el proceso de montarlas en el JS y 

    var tipow = "<?php echo $tipow2 ?>";
    var anow = "<?php echo $anow2 ?>";
```

Esta alli el script ajax que invoca al archivo url :"normat.php",

```
**buscarnorma.php**

 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <?php
       $tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
       $anow2=$_POST['anow'];
     //$tipow2="RESOLUCIONES";
     //$anow2="2016";
    ?>
        <title>Normatividad</title>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
    a:link {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var tipow = "<?php echo $tipow2 ?>";
                    var anow = "<?php echo $anow2 ?>";
                    var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                      "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                       "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax":{
                            url :"normat.php", // json datasource
                             data: {'tipow' : tipow, 'anow' : anow},
                            type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                            error: function(){  // error handling
                                $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                                $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3"> No hay Información </th></tr></tbody>');
                                $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                            }
                        }
                    } );
                } );
            </script>
            <style>
                div.container {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    max-width:760px;
                }
                div.header {
                    margin: 100px auto;
                    line-height:30px;
                    max-width:760px;
                }
                body {
                    background: #f7f7f7;
                    color: #333;
                    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue,Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
          <p><a href="index_principio.php"><img src="arribanormatividad2.png" width="629" height="133"></a></p>
            <table id="employee-grid"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th colspan="5"><?php echo $tipow2  ?>  <?php echo $anow2  ?></th>
                          </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="9%">Numero</th>
                                <th width="12%">Año</th>
                                <th width="53%">Descripción</th>
                                <th width="17%">Fecha</th>
                                <th width="9%">Estado</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
          </table>
                    <br>
          Realizado por: Eduardo Arroyo Teherán </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

el archivo normat.php muestra el resultado segun las variables pasadas

```
    <?php
    /* Database connection start */
    include("access.php");
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    $tipoow = $_POST["tipow"]; 
    $anoow = $_POST["anow"]; 
    /* Database connection end */
    // storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
    $requestData= $_REQUEST;
    $columns = array( 
    // datatable column index  => database column name
        0 =>'id', 
        1 =>'numero',
        2=> 'ano',
        3=> 'descripcion',
        4=> 'fecha',
        5=> 'estado',
        6=> 'archivo',
        7=> 'pagina',
        8=> 'tipo'
    );
    // getting total number records without any search
    $sql = "SELECT id, numero, ano, descripcion, fecha, estado, archivo, pagina, tipo";
    $sql.=" FROM normativa WHERE tipo='".$tipoow."' AND ano='".$anoow."'";
    //$sql.=" FROM normativa WHERE tipo='DECRETOS' AND ano='2017'";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("");
    $totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.
    if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
        // if there is a search parameter
        $sql ="SELECT id, numero, ano, descripcion, fecha, estado, archivo, pagina, tipo";
        $sql.=" FROM normativa";
        $sql.=" WHERE tipo='".$tipoow."' AND ano='".$anoow."' AND (numero LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";    // $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
        $sql.=" OR descripcion LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
        $sql.=" OR fecha LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%'";
        $sql.=" OR estado LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%')";


        $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("");

        $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result without limit in the query 
        $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; // $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc , $requestData['start'] contains start row number ,$requestData['length'] contains limit length.
        $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(""); // again run query with limit

    } else {    
    // ACA ES DONDE SALE AL PRINCIPIO--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $sql = "SELECT id, numero, ano, descripcion, fecha, estado, archivo, pagina, tipo";
        //$sql.=" FROM normativa WHERE tipo='DECRETOS' AND ano='2017'";
        $sql.=" FROM normativa WHERE tipo='".$tipoow."' AND ano='".$anoow."'";
        $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".
        $requestData['length']."   ";
        $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("");
    //<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4">   
    }
    $data = array();
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
        $nestedData=array(); 
        //str_pad( $row[ 'numero' ], 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );
        $nestedData[] =  '<a href=/normatividad/files/'.$row["archivo"].'.pdf#page='.$row["pagina"].' target="_blank">'.str_pad( $row[ 'numero' ], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT ).'</a>';
        $nestedData[] =  '<a href=/normatividad/files/'.$row["archivo"].'.pdf#page='.$row["pagina"].' target="_blank">'.$row["ano"].'</a>';
        $nestedData[] = '<a href=/normatividad/files/'.$row["archivo"].'.pdf#page='.$row["pagina"].' target="_blank">'.$row["descripcion"].'</a>';
        $nestedData[] = '<a href=/normatividad/files/'.$row["archivo"].'.pdf#page='.$row["pagina"].' target="_blank">'.$row["fecha"].'</a>';
        $nestedData[] = '<a href=/normatividad/files/'.$row["archivo"].'.pdf#page='.$row["pagina"].' target="_blank">'.$row["estado"].'</a>';
        $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
    $json_data = array(
                "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
                "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
                "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
                "data"            => $data   // total data array
                );
    echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format
    ?>
```

LO QUE NO ENTIENDO ES PRO QUE SI HAGO PRUEBAS ESCRIBIENDO LOS DATOS EN LAS VARIABLES QUE SE PASAN Y ASI SI FUNCIONA....

por ejemplo: comento las variables y pongo texto asi:

```
    //$tipow2=$_POST['tipow'];
    //$anow2=$_POST['anow'];
    $tipow2="RESOLUCIONES";
    $anow2="2016";
```

y asi si funciona....

Answer (score 0):

Hola he revisado tu codigo y en `<option value=" <?php echo $row['ano'] ?> " >` tienes espacios en el value por lo que al pasar las variables se pasan como " 2020 " entonces al hacer tu consulta en la base de datos no coincidiran ya que posee espacio entonces debe quedar de la siguiente manera en tus dos select : `<option value="<?php echo $row['ano'] ?>" >`.

Por favor prueba eso, espero sea la solución.

, saludos.

Comment: Hola Efectivamente ese era el error... estaba ingresando espacios al principio y al final... increíble que por un espacio estaba enloqueciendome jejejejeje MiL Graciassss

Comment: Hola, que bueno que puede ayudarte, Suerte con tu proyecto......